# Usage of " only to"

Tags: commas, to-infinitive

Could you help me understand the following structure:

This sentence is from Advanced Grammar in Use: " Note, however, that the situation or event does not have to continue until the time of the speaking, **only to** have some connection or relevance to the present time."

I thought " only to" can only be used to state unpleasant situation like " He spent years studying medicine, only to realize he wanted to study art."

Comment: The syntax and meanings are different. In the first, it's *[the situation] **only** [has] **to** have some connection...* In the second, ***only*** corresponds to ***for no better result than** [to realise...].*

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! I very much appreciate it!

Comment: A point about the grammar. "Only to" is not a grammatical unit (not a constituent). The "to" belongs with the verb "have". "Only" is a focusing adverb modifying the _to_-infinitival clause "to have some connection or relevance to the present time."

Comment: I can understand why a beginner would have difficulty with that sentence. It isn't at all clear. It would be much clearer if it said "... it only has to have some connection...".

Answer (score 0):

This is a parallel structure, the subject and verb in the second part have been omitted as they parallel the subject and verb of the first.  If I re-insert them I get:

> It does not have **to continue** until the time of the speaking, [it] only [has] **to have** some connection....

Here is a simpler example with apples:

> He does not like all fruit, only apples.

Comment: Thanks so much James!